# Identify "Start" and "End" date of a trip in SQL?

Tags: sql, db2

I want to get the start and end date of the trip from a table as shown below -

[image]

I have tried Min(Date) and then Max(Date) Group by Line_Number,Country
Also
LEAD function

Preferred Outcome

[image]

Comment: could you please explain he logic? why for 2nd line max date is 1/07/2019?

Comment: As per of my thinking, subsequent date should should be consider as start date and end date.

Comment: @fa06 the 2nd line max date is 1/07/2019 as that's when his 2nd trip finished and started on 27/06/2019.

Comment: @KiranDesai would you be able to give an example of what you mean. :)

Comment: @AbhishekParashar, is there any trip no there in your table?

Comment: @fa06 there are no trips that are missing from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Gaps and Islands...

Try this:

```
with tab (line_number, date, country) as (values
  (123456, date('2019-05-20'), 'London')
, (123456, date('2019-05-21'), 'London')
, (123456, date('2019-05-22'), 'London')
, (123456, date('2019-06-27'), 'London')
, (123456, date('2019-06-28'), 'London')
, (123456, date('2019-06-29'), 'London')
, (123456, date('2019-06-30'), 'London')
, (123456, date('2019-07-01'), 'London')
)
, a as (
select t.*
-- OLAP function sums the "flags" computed below,
-- so each group with consecutive dates has its distinct group number
, sum
(
-- The expression below 
-- returns 1 if date of the current row is 1 day after the date of the previous row
-- in the corresponding group (line_number, country) ordered by date
-- and 0 otherwise
case when date = lag(date) over (partition by line_number, country order by date) + 1 day then 0 else 1 end
) over (partition by line_number, country order by date) grp_num
from tab t
)
select 
  line_number
, min(date) as start_date
, max(date) as end_date
, country
--, grp_num
from a
group by line_number, country, grp_num;
```

Comment: Thank you @Mark Barinstein. the query worked for me. i was able to change a few things to be able to retrieve information directly from table to populate your with tab clause.  

Would you able to assist me write this so this can me executed in Netezza aswel. 

So i tried editing but keeps giving me error.

Comment: Would you able to assist me write this so this can me executed in Netezza aswel. 

So i tried editing but keeps giving me error.

Comment: with tab (line_number, date, country) as ( Select line_number, date, country from Daily_usage_table
)
, a as (
select t.*
, sum
(case when date = lag(date) over (partition by line_number, country order by date) + 1 day then 0 else 1 end
) over (partition by line_number, country order by date) grp_num
from tab t
)

Comment: select 
  line_number
, min(date) as start_date
, max(date) as end_date
, country
--, grp_num
from a
group by line_number, country, grp_num;

Comment: error                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ^ found "DAY" (at char 458) expecting `AND' or `AT' or `BETWEEN' or `IN' or `IS'